# Perl q function or single quote doesn't return the string literal of UNC path correctly

Tags: perl, string-literals

Perl's q function or single quote is supposed to return the string literal as typed (except `\'`). But it doesn't work as expected for the following scenario.
I want to print the following UNC path

```
\\dir1\dir2\dir3
```

So I have used

```
my $path = q(\\dir1\dir2\dir3);
```

OR

```
my $path = '\\dir1\dir2\dir3';
```

But this skips one backslash at the front.
So if I print it i.e. `print $path;` it prints

```
\dir1\dir2\dir3
```

I want to know why? I have to type 3 or 4 backslashes at the beginning of the UNC path to make it work as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

> **q/STRING/**
>
> **'STRING'**
>
> A single-quoted, literal string. A backslash represents a backslash unless followed by the delimiter or another backslash, in which case the delimiter or backslash is interpolated.

Change:

```
my $path = q(\\dir1\dir2\dir3);
```

to:

```
my $path = q(\\\dir1\dir2\dir3);
```

---

As for why, it's because Perl lets you include the quote delimiter in your string by escaping it with a backslash:

```
my $single_quote = 'This is a single quote: \'';
```

But if a backslash before the delimiter always escaped the delimiter, there would be no way to end a string with a backslash:

```
my $backslash = 'This is a backslash: \'; # nope
```

Allowing backslashes to be escaped too takes care of that:

```
my $backslash = 'This is a backslash: \\';
```

Comment: `\d` is literally `\d` inside a `q()` expression, so you can get away with 3 initial backslashes

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly enough, there is only one way to type in double backslashes in a perl string without it being interpolated as a single backslash.
As all the other answers showed,  any of the quote operators treat backslashes as  a backslash unless there is another one following it directly.

The only way to get the double backslashes to display exactly as you have typed them is to use a [single quote here-doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3C%3C_EOF_).

```
my $path = <<'VISTA';  
\\dir1\dir2\dir3 
VISTA
chomp $path;
print $path."\n";
```

Would print it exactly as you've typed it in.